# Menu items in the navigation drawer is not showing properly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, navigation-drawer

Following is the code of my `activity_main_drawer`. However, in the xml design view there is a `TextView` logout in the drawer. I have not added this text. How can I remove that text?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 tools:showIn="navigation_view">

 <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/profile_icon"
        android:title="Profile"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:icon="@drawable/find_donor_icon"
        android:title="Edit Profile" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:icon="@drawable/password_icon"
        android:title="Change Password" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/logout_icon"
        android:title="Logout" />
 </group>

 <group
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/share"
                android:icon="@drawable/share_icon"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/rate"
                android:icon="@drawable/rate_icon"
                android:title="Rate App on Play Store" />
        </menu>
 </group>

</menu>
```

highlighted Logout Text is error

[image]

Comment: why not add the last two menu options to the same group? try doing that.

Comment: @SripadRaj if i write menu items in the first group i will not get the horizontal divider line, above share button

Comment: I believe you have added a title to the sub menu in your java code, something like this `Menu submenu = menu.addSubMenu("Logout");`. Is that right? If yes, just make it `Menu submenu = menu.addSubMenu("");` and try.

Comment: @SripadRaj there is nothing like that code in Java file, its just XML design view, if there is anything in java file it is displayed when app is running not in Design view of XML file

Answer (score 3):

**Just remove** `<menu>` **and** `</menu>` **from the second** `<group>` **code** and then it will not show the *"Logout"* text.

So, the modified code would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 tools:showIn="navigation_view">

 <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/profile_icon"
        android:title="Profile"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:icon="@drawable/find_donor_icon"
        android:title="Edit Profile" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:icon="@drawable/password_icon"
        android:title="Change Password" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/logout_icon"
        android:title="Logout" />
 </group>

 <group
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <item
                android:id="@+id/share"
                android:icon="@drawable/share_icon"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/rate"
                android:icon="@drawable/rate_icon"
                android:title="Rate App on Play Store" />

 </group>

</menu>
```

And the **Output** will be:

[image: Output after modified code]

Answer (score 0):

Remove second group in menu **attribute** used like below ...

```
 <group
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/rate"
            android:title="Rate App on Play Store" />
 </group>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
            android:title="Profile" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/edit"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_person"
            android:title="Edit Profile" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_security"
            android:title="Change Password" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
            android:title="Logout" />
    </group>

    <group
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/rate"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_activity_log"
            android:title="Rate App on Play Store" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

And it looks like the following. Please change the icons as per your requirement.

[image]

Comment: i have used some image on menu it show properly. check profile and edit profile image is transpart or not.